# Best way to list the items through a card using node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am a newbie in chatbot and i am using microsoft bot framework.I want to list the items that my knowlegde base has trained with. What kind of cards can be used to prompt the user like "Hey user, I am trained with these list of items 1. .. 2. .. 3. .. "
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cards, it is important to know which channel you will be using because they render differently on different channels.  I would go through the [rich cards readme.md here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards) as well as this [adaptive cards readme.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards).  Those are great samples you can play around with to see what suits your needs. also [adaptivecards.io](http://adaptivecards.io)  and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status) is a list of channel supported by adaptive cards

Comment: Also note that Adaptive Cards are in pre-release, so things could change... however, that would be the way to go, in my opinion.